# Find Path in a Maze with bfs

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have a maze which consists of a dictionary (path), the maze has a dimension of (8,8).
In the dictionary is decleared if it's possible to move up, down, left or right.

Now I want to find the path with the BFS algorithm.
With the help of some videos and articles I could find a way from the start point to the end point. But I don't know how to print the actual way.
This is my code so far:

```
#--- Clear Terminal
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

import collections

paths = {   (0, 0): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 2): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (0, 3): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 5): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 6): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 7): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 0): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 2): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 3): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (1, 4): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 5): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (1, 6): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (2, 0): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 2): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 3): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (2, 4): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (2, 5): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 6): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 0): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (3, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (3, 2): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 3): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (3, 4): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 5): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 6): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 0): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 1): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (4, 2): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (4, 3): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True},
            (4, 5): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 6): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 0): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 1): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 2): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 3): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 5): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 6): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 0): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 1): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 2): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 3): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 5): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 6): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (7, 0): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 2): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 3): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 5): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 6): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (7, 7): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}}

start = (5, 5)
end = (2, 2)

queue = collections.deque()
queue.append(start)
seen = set([start])

while queue:
    path = queue.popleft()
    i, j = path
    print(path)
    if (i,j) == end:
        print("We found the end")
        break

    #--- check up
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("U") == True) and ((i - 1, j) not in seen):
        queue.append((i - 1, j))
        seen.add((i - 1, j))

    #--- check Down
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("D") == True) and ((i + 1, j) not in seen):
        queue.append((i + 1, j))
        seen.add((i + 1, j))

    #--- check Left
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("L") == True) and ((i, j - 1) not in seen):
        queue.append((i, j - 1))
        seen.add((i, j - 1))

    #--- check Left
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("R") == True) and ((i, j + 1) not in seen):
        queue.append((i, j + 1))
        seen.add((i, j + 1))
```

Does anyone know how to keep track of the correct path?

This is where I got the infomration about the bfs: [BFS](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/maze-problem-in-python-b303797b03ee)

Answer (score 1):

The path can be found by maintaining a dictionary that stores the previous element.

```
import collections

def print_path(start,goal):
    print("Path :")
    current = goal
    print(current)
    while current != start:
        current = parent[current]
        print(current)

paths = {   (0, 0): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 2): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (0, 3): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 5): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 6): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (0, 7): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 0): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 2): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 3): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (1, 4): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 5): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (1, 6): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (1, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (2, 0): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 2): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 3): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (2, 4): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (2, 5): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 6): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (2, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 0): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (3, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (3, 2): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 3): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (3, 4): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 5): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 6): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (3, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 0): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 1): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (4, 2): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (4, 3): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True},
            (4, 5): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 6): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (4, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 0): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 1): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 2): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 3): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (5, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 5): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 6): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (5, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 0): {'U': False, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 1): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 2): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 3): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 5): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (6, 6): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (6, 7): {'U': True, 'D': True, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (7, 0): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 1): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 2): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 3): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 4): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 5): {'U': False, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': True}, 
            (7, 6): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': True, 'R': False}, 
            (7, 7): {'U': True, 'D': False, 'L': False, 'R': False}}

start = (5, 5)
end = (2, 2)

queue = collections.deque()
queue.append(start)
seen = set([start])
parent = {}
while queue:
    path = queue.popleft()
    i, j = path
    print(path)
    if (i,j) == end:
        print("We found the end")
        print_path(start,end)
        break

    #--- check up
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("U") == True) and ((i - 1, j) not in seen):
        queue.append((i - 1, j))
        seen.add((i - 1, j))
        parent[(i - 1 ,j)] = (i, j)

    #--- check Down
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("D") == True) and ((i + 1, j) not in seen):
        queue.append((i + 1, j))
        seen.add((i + 1, j))
        parent[(i + 1,j)] = (i, j)

    #--- check Left
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("L") == True) and ((i, j - 1) not in seen):
        queue.append((i, j - 1))
        seen.add((i, j - 1))
        parent[(i,j - 1)] = (i, j)

    #--- check Left
    if (paths.get((i, j)).get("R") == True) and ((i, j + 1) not in seen):
        queue.append((i, j + 1))
        seen.add((i, j + 1))
        parent[(i,j + 1)] = (i, j)
```